# Unable to call web service from windows application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created a windows application. From this windows application i am trying to execute a function in webservice. But i am getting an error.

'Unable to automatically step in to the server'

Please help me solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error can occur when you are trying to step into a web service [see Stepping Into an XML Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc57803s.aspx). It can occur whenever ASP.NET is not set up properly.

Comment: i provided you a link..did you go there?

Comment: Yes sir.. i just need to execute a function in webservice from my windows application. How it is possible?

Comment: you need to have certain set of permission or admin account, in order to step into WebMethod running on remote server machine.

Comment: ok fine... i dont need to debugg..but i want to call a function in webservice from my windows application

Comment: may hope that [site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163821.aspx) would work..:)